# My Raspberry Pi is crashed and I'm not able to access it with SSH or SFTP. I need to backup my USB Drive mounted with Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, hard-drive, driver, raspbian-lite

My device is Raspberry Pi 3B with Raspbian stretch lite OS installed.
I was followed [this](https://blog.alexellis.io/attach-usb-storage/) tutorial to mount USB drive with my Raspberry Pi. But today my Raspberry Pi crashed for trying to uninstall `transmission-daemon` using `sudo apt purge transmission-daemon`. I'm not sure if it's the causes of the problem but after using this command I'm no longer able to connect my Raspberry Pi server with SSH or SFTP. To unmount the USB drive I need to use below commands:

```
$ sudo umount /mnt/pidrive1 
$ sudo fsck /dev/sda1
```

But I'm not even able to access with my Raspberry Pi with SSH. 
If I just unplug it from my Raspberry Pi and plug it on my PC, Windows asks me to format the USB drive.
So how can I backup the USB drive?

**Update:** It seems like, my USB drive is corrupted or something after using `transmission-daemon` . I tried to format it but didn't work.

**Edit:** One more thing, after successfully installing `transmission-daemon`, I downloaded a 6gb torrent file with it. But it was stuck at 30%. Then I opened my Raspberry Pi with SFTP, it worked fine but the USB drive folder wasn't opening. Then I tried to restart my RPI with the command `sudo reboot` but reboot didn't work. Then I power off my RPI and power on again. Then I tried to open USB drive folder but still didn't work. Then I tried to uninstall `transmission-daemon` and the command stuck there. After half an hour later I power off my RPI and power on again then I wasn't able to access my RPI.

Comment: Not sure how to approach your question as it seems you've got a lot going on (i.e. potentially multiple issues). Let's try to clarify some things first: 1. What type of USB drive are you using? 2. What did `fsck` report after you ran it last? 3. Have you ever mounted an `ext4` drive on your WIndows machine?

Comment: @Seamus 1. My USB drive is TwinMOS X3 USB 30 and it's 32GB. 2. I don't remember the fsck report. 3. I don't know what is that.

Comment: 1. OK, so it's what some call a "thumb drive".  2. OK then, I'll assume there were no issues. 3. `ext4` is the name of the [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) that Raspberry Pi uses, and the one you set up when you followed the tutorial you referenced. So here's the thing: There's not enough info in your question to pinpoint the issue (no fault of yours - it's just the way it is), and I rather doubt that we could suss it all out here in the Comments section. So I'm going to post an "answer" that's more a series of things to try. Look for that later in the day or tomorrow.

Comment: In the meantime, there is what appears to be a [verified set of installation instructions for `transmission-daemon` on the RPi here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=51219). I don't know if you still want to use the `transmission-daemon`, but I do think you'll benefit from reading through this, and the follow-on questions.

Comment: @Seamus Thanks. But it seems like my USB Drive is corrupted. Now I'm not even able to format it.

Comment: Maybe not... I've had Windows refuse to format drives that were formatted with non-MS file systems. But not to push... are you saying you want to give up on this?

Comment: @Seamus No. I still want to fix it.

Comment: OK then, I'll post an answer soon. It won't be a complete answer because you'll need to make decisions that can't be made at this point. So we'll work out a way to do this without resorting to "extended discussions in comments", which are against the rules, and we're near the limit already :)

Answer (score 2):

It is very likely that your USB drive is formated with the `ext4` filesystem. This is the default filesystem from Raspbian but Windows can't read it. There are some options to get access to your drive. The simplest solution is to use a pc with linux operating system of course, e.g. with Debian or Ubuntu. If not available or doable you can use a live system to boot from CD or USB stick. Most linux distributions can run as live system (Debian, Ubuntu, ...). There are also second party drivers available for Windows with that you can read `ext4` with Windows. I have less experience with Windows so I can't tell you what drivers available. But there are many Windows guys here on the site. They can tell you what drivers best to use with Windows.

Answer (score 1):

To amplify @Ingo's answer, if you followed the tutorial you referenced in your question, then your USB drive is formatted with the `ext4` [file system.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) Note that the `ext4` file system is foreign to your Windows PC, and it won't read any device formatted with `ext4` without installing some specialized software on Windows.

But let's take some steps to try to tackle your problem. Please be aware that due to your current situation (unable to access RPi), and the lack of details, I will have to make assumptions/guesses, and not all of them will be correct. I don't think I will make things worse, but that is a possibility. If you're OK with that, we'll proceed in an [iterative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration) fashion.

My best guess is that the tutorial you followed has led you into this situation. I don't understand what, if anything, purging the `transmission-daemon` had to do with this, but I feel there are two issues with that tutorial:
1. use of `\dev\sda` in lieu of a more specific label, and
2.failure to add the `nofail` option to your `/etc/fstab` configuration

This leads me to suspect that you can't login because the boot process has halted (due to lack of `nofail` in `/etc/fstab`), and this because it doesn't recognize your USB thumb drive for reasons we don't understand now.

Assuming that the red LED on your RPi is still illuminated when you apply power, I think you should first establish that your RPi can be restored to a functional state. There are two ways to do this:
1. Re-install stretch lite on your SD card, and start from the beginning
2. Edit the `/etc/fstab` file to remove the line you added to mount your USB drive.

Option 1. is likely to be quicker, easier and more certain, but if you have data on your SD card that you need to recover, then Option 2. will be our course of action. Just as a preview of Option 2, if you are considering that option, I will suggest that you create a [bootable USB stick iaw this procedure](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1). **NOTE: You will need another USB stick for this unless you want to overwrite everything on the USB stick you've been using.** This procedure will result in you running **`Ubuntu live`** on your Windows machine, but you **won't install Ubuntu on your Windows PC** (unless you elect to do so later). Running Ubuntu will allow you to mount your SD card (`ext4` file system), and edit your `/etc/fstab` file.

I'll stop here, while you consider your options. Post a Comment to this answer when you've decided how you wish to proceed, or if you have questions. We'll pick up after I hear from you.

Status: stretch lite has been re-installed, and your RPi is pristine again :).

On the chance that your original USB drive (TwinMOS X3) has not been corrupted, we'll try to mount it first. Make an SSH connection to your RPi, then plug in the TwinMOS X3 USB drive. From your SSH terminal window enter the following:

```
lsblk --fs
```

Hopefully, you will get something that looks similar to this, but it won't be an exact match:

> NAME        FSTYPE LABEL       UUID              MOUNTPOINT
>       sda
>       └─sda1      ext4  TWINMOSX3  5AFA-59C4

The important parts are that you have at least one partition (`sda1` in this case, but it could be `sdb1`, etc), and the `FSTYPE` is `ext4`. The value in the `LABEL` column could be almost anything; it's a text string that can be changed. The `UUID` value is meaningless for our purposes because this is a USB drive (as opposed to a "real" drive).

Next, if your `lsblk --fs` output was similar to that above, check the USB drive with `fsck`. NOTE: Use the partition from the result above; `sda1` in this case, but it could also be `sdb1`, etc.

```
sudo fsck /dev/sda1
```

You should get something that looks like this:

> fsck from util-linux 2.29.2
>       exfatfsck 1.2.5
>       Checking file system on /dev/sda1.
>       File system version           1.0
>       Sector size                 512 bytes
>       Cluster size                 32 KB
>       Volume size                  15 GB
>       Used space                   26 MB
>       Available space              15 GB
>       Totally 1 directories and 13 files.
>       File system checking finished. No errors found.

If you see the magic words `No errors found`, things are looking bright, and we should be able to mount the drive!

```
mkdir /home/pi/mntThumbDrv 
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /home/pi/mntThumbDrv
```

Assuming no errors, check the contents:

```
ls -l /home/pi/mntThumbDrv
```

Hopefully, you'll find all of the files here you expected to find.

If you do find there are errors on your drive, it likely means that it is corrupted, and should be re-formatted.

> NOTE: Reformatting will overwrite any data on your drive, so if your drive is corrupted, but has data that you wish to try and recover, STOP HERE. 
>   Data recovery tools are available, but beyond the scope of this answer. Once you've committed to the re-format and overwrite, here's how to proceed:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1 -L TWINMOSX3-32GB
```

Note that this command will format the partition `sda1` using the `ext4` file system and write a "label" `-L` (TWINMOSX3-32GB in this case) to the drive. The label should be descriptive, but most importantly make sure this label is a unique name; i.e. **DO NOT** apply this same label to any other USB/removable drive. I'll explain why in a moment.

With all of that successfully behind us, it's time to `mount` the drive. Following is the sequence I use, and it reflects my preferences, so feel free to alter it. There are a couple of steps you should not alter unless you have a reason for doing so; I've annotated those:

```
mkdir /home/pi/mntThumbDrv  
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /home/pi/mntThumbDrv  
touch testfile.txt  
echo "this is a test" > testfile.txt  
mv testfile.txt ~/mntThumbDrv  
cat ~/mntThumbDrv/testfile.txt
```

Which should yield:

> this is a test

If so, our drive is mounted properly, and working (pending any niggling permissions issues that can be addressed with `chmod`).

If this drive will find recurring use on this RPi, we'll want to automate the `mount` process. Unmount the drive first, and then edit `/etc/fstab` as follows:

```
sudo umount ~/mntThumbDrv  
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

This will open `/etc/fstab` in the `nano` text editor. Once open, add one line to `/etc/fstab` as follows:

```
LABEL=TWINMOSX3-32GB /home/pi/mntThumbDrv ext4 rw,user,nofail 0 0
```

You should read `man fstab` and/or `man mount` to understand what this string means, and you may change these options as you choose. **However:

1. Use the same LABEL string you assigned during the `mkfs` operation above

2. To avoid losing control of your system during reboot, you must include `nofail` as a mount option.**

Save the edited file `/etc/fstab`, and exit the editor.

You should test your configuration to ensure it's working properly. With the USB drive still plugged into your RPi:

```
sudo mount -av
```

Which should yield:

> /proc                    : already mounted
>   /boot                    : already mounted
>   /                        : ignored
>   /home/pi/mntThumbDrv     : successfully mounted

Next, unmount and remove the USB drive from the RPi :

```
sudo umount ~/mntThumbDrv
```

After physically unplugging the drive from the USB slot in the RPi, let's run `mount` as follows:

```
sudo mount -av
```

Which should yield:

> /proc                    : already mounted
>   /boot                    : already mounted
>   /                        : ignored

Indicating that `mount` completed successfully. Note that the documentation suggests that `nofail` simply suppresses the error message, but in practice (at least on currently-configured RPi) absence of the `nofail` option for a missing drive seems to derail the boot process as well. Hopefully, this will be resolved in the future.

Hope this has helped. Much of this [process is available at my GitHub site](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/ExternalDrives.md), which is updated from time to time.

Comment: @Bangladesh71: Once you've considered the two options I offered, please let me know how you'd like to proceed: 1. re-install Raspbian from scratch, or 2. attempt repair of your existing installation.

Comment: Done and I want to re-install raspbian from scratch.

Comment: I successfully installed Raspbian and got access with SSH and SFTP but still I'm not able to use that USB drive with my Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Yes. That is what I have just mounted now. It's working fine but 16 GB.

Comment: Just done. So how to fix the USB drive?

Comment: @Bangladesh71: No reply from you in a while. I'm going to add some more to my answer, and knock off for the evening. We can pick this up when you're ready. Also, consider deleting your earlier comments as they've all been incorporated in your question and the answer.

Comment: Just used the `sudo fsck /dev/sdb1` command. It is only showing `fsck from util-linux 2.29.2`. Should I stop this command by `CTRL+Z` ?

Comment: @Bangladesh71 Try to use the option `-f`, means *force checking*. It doesn't harm. So the command looks like `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb1`.

Comment: @Ingo Still same.

Comment: @Bangladesh71: Apparently, the `lsblk --fs` command showed your USB drive on /dev/sdb1 - is that correct?

Comment: @Seamus Not similar to yours.

Comment: @Bangladesh71:  Please post the output of that command as an EDIT to your question.